# How to make "Chat with an expert" disappear after ending the chat?

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot

I have two Bots, Tom and Tevez, these Bots run on a SPA (Single Page Application)

The SPA has two buttons:

[image]

The following happens: Users can talk normally with one of the Bots, but when he closes the conversation with Tom (for example) and clicks to talk to Tevez, Tom's Bot opens...

Examples:

1.
[image]
2.
[image]
3.
[image]
4.
[image]
5.
[image]

The same thing is in reverse, when the user talks to Tevez, closes the conversation, and clicks to talk to Tom, Bot Tevez opens...

I know the obvious solution would be to reload the web page, but the client doesn't want the page to reload as it's a SPA...

So, the solution I see is to kill this instance of the bot, that is, as soon as the user ends the chat, this "Chat with an Expert" disappears!

And that way, when the user clicks to chat with another Bot, the correct Bot instance would be loaded! Please help me.

Comment: I tried to clean all cookies (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript) always button is clicked, but this doesn't resolve

Comment: what happens when you click on those 2 button? can you share the code for that?

Comment: when the page is loaded the bot doesn't show, the bot only shows when I click on some button, and when I close the bot, the bot doesn't disappear... This is a problem because when I click on bot Tom (for example) I cannot change and talk to Tevez, you understood?